# Back up saved games in Galaxy on Fire 2

Tags: android, galaxy-on-fire-2

How can I back up saved games in Galaxy on Fire 2 on my Android phone, so that I can restore them e.g. when the phone breaks etc.?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a good file manager on your phone (I personally use Solid Explorer), you can navigate to the game's folder (Android/data/net.fishlabs.gof2hdallandroid2012) and make a copy of the save files you find in there. You can then put that copy anywhere. Sadly, Fishlabs made the save games device-locked at some point in the last few years, so you cannot simply copy paste savegames to a new device, only to the one it was created on. I found this out the hard way a few days ago.